# How to exit the application in navigation composable in Android

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have an application which has three screens. The first one is **Onboarding** after that there is **Home** and then **Profile**. If the information is not present, the app opens to Onboarding and if already there, then it goes to Home.

The home page has a button which navigates to profile. The profile page has a log out button and when the user presses it, it goes back to Onboarding.

My problem is that after the user presses the log out button, it goes back to Onboarding as expected, but when you press the back button while on Onboarding screen, instead of exiting the app, it goes back to Profile screen. Here is the navigation:

```
@Composable
fun NavigationComposable() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    val firstName = sp.getString("firstName", null)
    val lastName = sp.getString("lastName", null)
    val email = sp.getString("email", null)

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    if (firstName == null && lastName == null && email == null) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Onboarding.route
        ) {
            composable(Onboarding.route) {
                Onboarding(navController = navController)
            }
            composable(Home.route) {
                Home(navController = navController)
            }
            composable(Profile.route) {
                Profile(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    } else {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Home.route
        ) {
            composable(Home.route) {
                Home(navController = navController)
            }
            composable(Profile.route) {
                Profile(navController = navController)
            }
            composable(Onboarding.route){
                Onboarding(navController = navController)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the Profile

```
@Composable
fun Profile(navController: NavController) {

      Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(10.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().apply();
                    navController.navigate(Onboarding.route)

                }) {
                    Text(text = "Log out")
                }
            }
      }
```

How can I change it to exit the app when on the Onboarding page?

Comment: What is the programming language? [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried your code. Please make use of NavOptions to set popupTo and popupinclusive of Navigation compose.

Here is the code:

```
@Composable
fun NavigationComposable() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    val firstName = sp.getString("firstName", null)
    val lastName = sp.getString("lastName", null)
    val email = sp.getString("email", null)

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val startDestination = if (firstName == null && lastName == null && email == null) {
        Onboarding.route
    } else {
        Home.route
    }
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        composable(Onboarding.route) {
            Onboarding(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(Home.route) {
            Home(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(Profile.route) {
            Profile(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: **Here I get the start destination using a condition**. It is a slight modification of your code. If applicable, make use of this.

Here is the code of Profile and Onboarding

1. Profile Screen

   ```
   @Composable
   fun Profile(navController: NavController) {

       Column(
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(10.dp),
           horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
       ) {
           Button(onClick = {
               val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(Home.route, true).build()
               navController.navigate(Onboarding.route, navOptions)

           }) {
               Text(text = "Log out")
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. OnBoarding Screen

   ```
   @Composable
   fun Onboarding(navController: NavController) {

       Column(
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(10.dp),
           horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
       ) {
           Button(onClick = {
               val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(Onboarding.route, true).build()
               navController.navigate(Home.route, navOptions)

           }) {
               Text(text = "To Home")
           }
       }
   }
   ```

As you can see, in both the screens, when you try to navigate, I have used navOptions to popUp the screen in the back stack. This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shreyas. It worked. Could you explain a bit about  `val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(Onboarding.route, true).build()` why we have Onboarding.route in it while we want to navigate to Home.route in the next line. Thanks again.

Comment: In navOptions, we will mention a route till which the back stack should be removed. So when you navigate from OnBoarding screen to home screen the onboarding screen will present in back stack so we are mentioning navOptions when we navigate to Home from onboarding to remove onboarding screen from back stack. I think this clarify your doubt

Answer (score -2):

To navigate from the profile screen to the onboarding screen while clearing the backstack in the Android Navigation Component, you can use the `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` attributes in your navigation graph. Here's how you can do it

1. Open your navigation graph XML file where you define your navigation destinations.
2. Create a new action that connects the profile screen to the onboarding screen.
3. In the action, set the `popUpTo` attribute to the ID of the destination that you want to clear the backstack up to (usually, it's the start destination).
4. Set the `popUpToInclusive` attribute to `true` to indicate that the destination you specified in `popUpTo` should also be removed from the backstack.

Here's an example XML snippet to help illustrate this:

```
<navigation>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="Profile">
        <!-- Other attributes for your profile fragment -->
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/onboardingFragment"
        android:name="com.example.OnboardingFragment"
        android:label="Onboarding">
        <!-- Other attributes for your onboarding fragment -->
    </fragment>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_profile_to_onboarding"
        app:destination="@id/onboardingFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/profileFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</navigation>
```

With this configuration, when you navigate from the profile screen to the onboarding screen using the `action_profile_to_onboarding` action, the backstack will be cleared up to and including the profile screen. This ensures that when you reach the onboarding screen, there is no previous history of profile screen in the backstack. Additionally handle the exit of your app via a dialog box as a good practice.

Comment: It appears that you think the person who wrote the question downvoted you, which isn't necessarily the case (or even likely).  My guess is that the downvote was from someone who felt that your answer likely was written with assistance from ChatGPT or another LLM, which is [not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).